# Узнать какую техологию использовали создатели сайта

Tags: php, html, http, веб-сервер, framework

Как понимаю  сервер отправляет по запросу  в браузер код без серверных скриптов, тогда как понять какой фреймворк использовали создатели сайта

Comment: спросить у них.

Comment: иногда просмотр html-кода страниц может помочь. популярные cms вы там точно определите

Comment: Есть еще сервисы определяющий cms например: https://itrack.ru/whatcms/

Comment: я пользуюсь плагином для хрома - Wappalyzer, в 80% показывет нормально

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй плагин для браузера - wappalyzer (есть для Chome или для Firefox).
Данный плагин, как раз определяет технологии которые использовались при создании сайта